# tableview row become empty

Tags: iphone

I have a TableView with subclassed tableviewCells.
Whenever the cell is tapped it will show a small article.
But when this article is viewed and I scroll the tableview, the cell will be empty and the text is at the bottom of my tableview.

I don't know how to fix it.
Can someone help me out on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean when you click on a cell, you get a new view? Or does your cell 'expand'? In anyway, you should check your cellForRowAtIndexPath, since scrolling tableviews triggers that. Check if you don't use some sort of double up without 'cleaning' the variables you should enter in the cells.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're doing. Are there two types of cells, or a master/detail navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: you must use different cell identifier because you reuse the cells.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `cellIdentifier`. Its got to do with `reusing` the `cell`.